# OpenStreetMap baselayer of just one country

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, basemap

In Leaflet map I want to have like you see above an OSM baselayer with only one country the rest of the world has to be just a blank, only with international border. How can we create this? which URL of tillelayer give us this result?

[image]

Comment: you will need your own tile server https://github.com/gagan-bansal/osm-for-my-country

Comment: From @TomazicM: OpenStreetMap is open vector map data set (see https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright), that can be used by anyone. OpenStrreetMap tiles is a tiled raster map, created from OpenStreetMap data, and intended exclusively for testing, not for production (see https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/). There are vector subsets for individual countries (see http://download.geofabrik.de/), but you would need a server to deploy them. There's plenty of other maps, based on OpenStreetData, and for that you should ask on OpenData SE https://opendata.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Leaflet plugin that lets you mask a tile layer:

https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas

The demo shows a region around Moscow:

http://aparshin.github.io/leaflet-boundary-canvas/examples/canvas-boundary-providers.html

[image]

but notice how labels get cropped at the edges:

[image]

Comment: This is much easier than the first method ! but the first method of having their own server is the one used on the example of my question